# Web Application Authentication integration best practice?

Tags: security, architecture

We have a Java Web Application that stores user authentication and authorisation information in database. It works well in the past until we want to integration with Active Directory.

The application database defines the user id as a primary key, this means when create a new user we have to create in two places, AD and Database, this is not what we want.

I am looking for solution to allow us create the user once only in AD. If such solution is not easy, if we are going to redesign the application, what would be the best practice to support integration with external services, as well as allow the application to be able to authenticate against its database?

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at `spring-security` and `spring-ldap` It works just fine with Active Directory and very easy to implement if you are familiar with spring.